# How can I vertically align my text lines?

Tags: html, css

I'm having a problem with vertical alignment with my text lines. I have two text lines, `<p>`, and I want to put the second one in the bottom of my `<div>` so I tried to do `vertical-align: bottom` and `text-bottom` and the `top` and `bottom` ones in my `<p>` and that didn't work.

```css
.header {
  grid-area: header;
  background-color: red;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: 'headerLeft rest headerRight';
  grid-template-columns: 10% 1fr 30%;
  padding: 5px;
}

.header p {
  margin: 0px;
}

.headerRight {
  grid-area: headerRight;
}

.headerRight p {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="layout">
  <div class="header">
    <div class="headerRight">
      <p style="margin: 0px 0px 0px 1px;"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/V2aWxOK.png" style="height: 13vh" /></p>
      <p><img src="https://i.imgur.com/V2aWxOK.png" style="height: 13vh" /></p>
      <p style="margin: 0px 5px 0px 0px">Ola</p>
      <br />
      <p style="margin: 0px 5px 0px 0px">Ola</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Which <p> you want to put at the bottom of which <div>

Comment: @MonikaMangal second one. Cause I want to put the first one at the top, its done per default, and the second one at the buttom.

Comment: So I'm assuming the only part of that code that's required for your problem is the `.headerRight` element, and its children (along with the associated CSS)?

Comment: @DavidThomas well I posted the .header and .headerRight only for sure. I think it's formated question now.

Comment: You're floating all P children of that div, which makes some properties like alignment not work quite like we might expect. Was there a reason you wanted all the children of headerRight to float?

Comment: @Nikki9696 I want to put all the content to the right, I dont know if exist a better way to do it, if it does just go for it.

Comment: @DavidThomas Yeah I think it is the best solution. Thank you for the awnser, the edits, and all of your patience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest the following, which involves some minor updates to your HTML; explanations are in the comments to the code itself:

```css
.header {
  grid-area: header;
  background-color: red;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: 'headerLeft rest headerRight';
  grid-template-columns: 10% 1fr 30%;
  padding: 5px;
}

.header p {
  margin: 0px;
}

.headerRight {
  grid-area: headerRight;
  
  /* here we specify the use of CSS Grid layout: */
  display: grid;
  /* define the top-and-bottom (0) and left-and-right (5px) grid
     gap gutters: */
  grid-gap: 0 5px;
  /* define the named areas of the grid: */
  grid-template-areas:
      ". paragraphAreaOne imageOne imageTwo"
      ". . imageOne imageTwo"
      ". paragraphAreaTwo imageOne imageTwo";
  
  /* define the sizing of the columns; here we have the first column
     taking up one fractional unit (1fr), with the other columns sized,
     using the repeat() function, at min-content in order to have those
     grid-columns sized to the minimum necessary to contain their content: */
  grid-template-columns: 1fr repeat(3, min-content);
  /* here we have three rows each sized, using the repeat() function,
     to size each row to min-content: */
  grid-template-rows: repeat(3, min-content);
}

/* positioning the various elements into the appropriate grid areas: */
.headerRight p:first-of-type {
  grid-area: paragraphAreaOne;
}

.headerRight p:nth-of-type(2) {
  grid-area: paragraphAreaTwo;
}

.headerRight img:first-of-type {
  grid-area: imageOne;
}

.headerRight img:nth-of-type(2) {
  grid-area: imageTwo;
}
```

```html
<div class="layout">
  <div class="header">
    <div class="headerRight">
      <!-- your img elements were wrapped in <p> elements, which were removed,
           partially for semantic reasons, and partially because they were
           simply unnecessary -->
      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/V2aWxOK.png" style="height: 13vh" />
      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/V2aWxOK.png" style="height: 13vh" />
      <p>Ola</p>
      <!-- there was a <br> element here which, when using a Grid layout
           serves no purpose, so was removed -->
      <p>Ola</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/3cdnbqk8/1/).

References:

- [`gap`/ `grid-gap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/gap)
- [`grid-template-areas`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-template-areas).
- [`grid-template-columns`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-template-columns).
- [`grid-template-rows`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-template-rows).
- [`min-content`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/width#min-content).
- [`repeat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/repeat).

Comment: Yeah so much clear and simple that I had.. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

you are using grid so u can use align-items:end to the header and it will align your elements to the bottom here take a look at it https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/align-items

Comment: I don't want all of my items and the end.

Comment: which one you want

Comment: On the header the second "Ola". I already have a solution in the question comments. If you want take a look what I want.